# Derived equivalence for two modules

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A=K[x]/(x^n)$ and $M_1$ and $M_2$ two basic generator of mod-A and let $B_i=End_A(M_i)$.
$B_1$ and $B_2$ are derived equivalent in case $M_1 \cong \Omega^1(M_2)$ in the stable category.

> Question: Can $B_1$ and $B_2$ be derived equivalent in case their non-projective parts are not in the same $\Omega$-orbit?